# How can I embed JSON from WireMock transformerParameters?

Tags: json, templates, parameters, response, wiremock

I have the following WireMock mapping file including `transformerParameters`. I want to embed JSON in body file.

mappings/parameters.json:

```json
{
    "request": {
        "urlPath": "/parameters"
    },
    "response": {
        "bodyFileName": "parameters.json",
        "transformers": ["response-template"],
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformerParameters": {
            "keyValue": { "key": "Value" }
        }
    }
}
```

__files/parameters.json:

```
{{ parameters.keyValue }}
```

The response is:

```
{key&#x3D;Value}
```

I need the following response:

```
{"key":"Value"}
```

How can I embed JSON from WireMock transformerParameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(self answer)

I found a template, if fields are not nested.

__files/parameters.json: (.hbs)

```
{ {{#each parameters.keyValue as |value key|
}}{{#if @last
    }}"{{key}}":"{{value}}"{{else
    }}"{{key}}":"{{value}}",{{/if}}{{/each}} }
```

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each